# How do I reference an object name as text in a label for a ggplot?

Tags: r, string, ggplot2, label

Basically I wish to mitigate the amount of re-coding I have to do when creating new plots by only changing the reference to the "xvar" object below...

```
xvar<-"n_Age"

ggplot(data=dat4,aes(x=n_Age,y=Count))+
  geom_smooth()+
  labs(x=xvar, y="Count")
```

This code works ok in the "labs" part of the statement (as it is referencing text) however in the "aes" component I need to re-specify n_Age. Can I not just use some syntax that removes the quotation marks from the xvar object, to actually reference the object?

Thanks,
Daniel.

Comment: could you add your data to the question (e.g. using dput) to make this reproducible, thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: The last example on the `ggplot2::aes` help page shows how to do this. It's probably a duplicate question as well.

Answer (score 5):

You can specify `aes_string` instead of `aes`:

```
xvar<-"n_Age"

ggplot(data=dat4,aes_string(x=xvar,y="Count"))+
  geom_smooth()+
  labs(x=xvar, y="Count")
```

Comment: `aes_string` was the function used in the two prior answers to similar questions that I found using the search strategy: `[r] pass character aes ggplot`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21230635/accesing-a-variable-in-a-ggplot-function/21230804#21230804, and 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24916502/creating-a-function-using-ggplot2/24916664#24916664

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is one instance where I use `get`

```
# silly data
dat4 <- data.frame("n_Age"=rnorm(100), "Count"=1:100)

xvar<-"n_Age"

ggplot(data=dat4,aes(x=get(xvar),y=Count))+
  geom_smooth()+
  labs(x=xvar, y="Count")
```